# Appending multiple html element to a div on .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently pulling photos from Flickr using an API call for a photo gallery. on click of the main image it is supposed to append it to a "recentlyViewed" div using a smaller size. Now part of this works, on click it does append to the div, but upon clicking the next image, the first image in the recently viewed is replaced with the second.

```
$('figure').each(function(index){ // Select all figures using .each 
          $(this).click(function(){ // register this(figure).click(ed) on

            $('recentlyViewed').html($(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-square')));

          }); 
        });
```

So like I said, it just doesn't append to the element. I have tried used .append and .appendTo but it just doesn't seem to effect it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is not enough code to understand your problem. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55436122/edit) and then the `[<>]` snippet editor and give us a [mcve]

Comment: .html() will replace whatever is there

Comment: we'll need to see more than this we need to be able to reproduce the problem. 
And you're not using the `index` keyword anywhere in your script.

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to see more than that; We need to be able to reproduce the problem. 
And you're not using the `index` keyword anywhere in your script!

That being said, I must underline that the following is *not* the actual solution.

As I don't do jQuery - I will try to demonstrate a possible solution for you using pure JavaScript, also being (re)branded as Vanilla.:

```
  [].slice.call( 
        document.querySelectorAll('figure')
        ).
        forEach( 
              function( x ) {
                    x.onclick = function( ) { /*reg fig clicked here*/ 
                    recentlyViewed.innerHTML = 
                    this.getAttribute('src')+", "+ this.getAttribute('data-square');
                    };             
              }
        );
```

we're assuming here that::
1. a clicked figure should get a click event registration linked to a function which presumably: 
    1.a) gives away its content url, alongside with some custom data-square attribute content.
2. also presuming that "recentlyViewed" is the ID of the HTML target content to be overwritten.